# Keyboad Events on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I m using a iframe inside a div to display modal dialogs in my project and having trouble with keyboard events. The div overlay mask does not prevent keyboard interaction with underlying elements.

I want keyboard events to trigger only on the opened popup (like ALT + R, CTRL + Uparrow). But now it triggers on the parent elements also. I have attached all keyboard events to $(document). Could someone please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue using Bootstrap 3 modal which does not allow keyboard events to be fired on parent.